# Scroll to the last row of text in Excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, spreadsheet

Would someone be able to tell me how I can make my spread sheet move the last row of text from VBA.

Currently I use the following code:

```
Range("p65536").End(xlUp).Select
```

This works, but it also moves to a particular column. I would like to do this but keep the current columns on the screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code:

`ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, Selection.Column).End(xlUp).Select`

Comment: Thanks - trying the following (which has a row count) does not appear to move the worksheet

    [ReportingSheet].Cells(finalRow, Selection.column).End(xlUp).Select

Answer (score 1):

What you want to change is `ScrollRow`.  If you also wanted to scroll horizontally you would set `ScrollColumn`.

```
Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
Set targetSheet = ActiveSheet   ' Refer to your sheet instead of ActiveSheet.

targetSheet.Activate    ' Make sure the worksheet is active to prevent errors.

With targetSheet.Cells(targetSheet.Rows.Count, Selection.Column).End(xlUp)
    .Select ' not required to change the focus/view
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = .Row
End With
```